# PHPDoc & Psalm - Annotate an "array of classes"

Tags: php, phpdoc, psalm-php

In my code I created an EventFactory like this:

```
private array $events = [
    'post_created' => PostCreatedEvent::class,
    'exercise_executed' => ExerciseExecutedEvent::class,
];

public function fromTopicAndData(string $topic, array $data) : Event
{
    if (! array_key_exists($topic, $this->events)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid Topic');
    }

    $event = ($this->events)[$topic];
    return $event::createFromData($data);
}
```

Both **PostCreatedEvent** and **ExerciseExecutedEvent** extends an abstract class **Event**.

Can you tell me if there is a way to annotate the array in such a way as not to receive error from Psalm?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Event` class declares `createFromData()` method the following docblock should do the trick:

```php
/** @var array<string, class-string<Event>> */
private array $events = [
    'post_created' => PostCreatedEvent::class,
    'exercise_executed' => ExerciseExecutedEvent::class,
];
```

Live demo: https://psalm.dev/r/da11fc8d8c